# Dash app cannot find pages folder when deploying on GCP using gunicorn

Tags: python, dockerfile, gunicorn, plotly-dash, google-cloud-run

I am trying to deploy my dash app which uses dash_extensions, Dash_proxy and has multiple pages in the pages folder on GCP cloud run using gunicorn but the app cannot find the pages folder. It works perfectly fine when I use the development server but breaks in the production server because it cannot find the folder path.

The app (following code is inside the `app.py` file):

```
app = DashProxy(use_pages=True, pages_folder=pages_folder, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SIMPLEX])
```

The `app.py` file and the `pages` folder are in the same directory

I have tried tried to following methods to get the folder path:

```
pages_folder="pages"
```

```
pages_folder=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "pages")
```

```
for p in Path('.').rglob('*'):
    if str(p).endswith('pages'):
        pages_folder = str(p)
        break
```

None of the above three work in when deploying on gcp using gunicorn through docker:

Dockerfile command:

```
CMD ["gunicorn"  , "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "app:server"]
```

[image]

But if I use dev server through docker like following code it works:

```
CMD python app.py
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to make it work with gunicorn?

Thanks for the help!

-Rexon

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue on a Debian VM. Would love to know if others have had an issue with Dash not recognizing the pages folder.

Comment: I also have this problem. Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I did. Just had to specify the root folder. This is what I did and it seems to work for me.

```
pages_folder=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__name__), "pages")

app = DashProxy(__name__,use_pages=True, pages_folder=pages_folder, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SIMPLEX])

server=app.server
```